# Quickest way to watch filesystem in Java

Tags: java

I know about org.apache.commons.io.monitor, but is there a briefer, more minimalist way to watch for new/changed files in a specific directory on the filesystem? E.g. some idiom in the range of 50-100 lines of code?

Comment: Never write your own code when you can just use a library.

Comment: @Philipp - Yeah, I always add giant dependencies to my project for one simple feature ...

Comment: @Lars - Java 7 includes this, and it would be fairly easy to roll your own basic solution in that many lines.

Comment: @Philipp That's an over generalization/simplification and of little help in this case. In this particular application, size matters. I should've mentioned that, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are OK with using Java 7, take a look at the new [FileSystem API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

E.g. code from that link:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;
Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           ENTRY_CREATE,
                           ENTRY_DELETE,
                           ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you pointed out commons.io provides a package of file monitoring classes in [`org.apache.commons.io.monitor`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) that you can use to build your own (only [63 lines of example code](http://andreinc.net/2012/06/30/writing-a-simple-file-monitor-in-java-using-commons-io/) including `main()`).  It's open source, so you can extract the code from there if you don't want to include the whole library and don't want to use Java 7 (or later).

It's very easy (and more efficient) using Java 7's [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) (see [45 lines of example code](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes) here).